# Is there a way to calculate $\int_{-a}^{-b}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$ when both $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate $$\int_{-a}^{-b}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$ for any $a$ and $b$ strictly positive real numbers. For the moment, i rely on a "brute" force approach that rely on using the expanded serie of the exponential function...

Comment: As @ConMan said, there won't be any nice answer to this integral (since ${\frac{e^{-x}}{x}}$ can't be integrated in terms of elementary functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the Exponential Integral function defined like:$$\text{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$we have:
:$$\int_{-a}^{-b}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du=\int_{-a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du-\int_{-b}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$ $$=\int_{-a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du-\int_{-b}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$ $$=-Ei\left(a\right)+Ei\left(b\right)= Ei\left(b\right)-Ei\left(a\right)$$
Then to compute this, we only need a reliable numeric method like the one provided in Numerical Recipes page 225:
https://www.cec.uchile.cl/cinetica/pcordero/MC_libros/NumericalRecipesinC.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The integral of $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ is given by the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function $Ei(x)$, and it cannot be written with elementary functions.

As the Wikipedia article notes, there are a few approximations for the function, although I can't offhand tell you what range they're good approximations in.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-a}^{-b}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du=\text{Ei}(b)-\text{Ei}(a)$$

For large values of $x$
$$\log (\text{Ei}(x))=x-\log(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n} n x^{-n}$$
where the $a_n$'s correspond to the indecomposable permutations (have a look at sequence $A003319$ in $OEIS$.

This leads to a relative error of $1$% as soon as $x \geq 8$,  $0.1$% as soon as $x > 10$,
$0.01$% as soon as $x > 11$

Comment: Indeed, shame on me, i didn't see that:$$\int_{-a}^{-b}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du=\int_{-a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du-\int_{-b}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$ $$=\int_{-a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du-\int_{-b}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$ $$=-Ei\left(a\right)+Ei\left(b\right)= Ei\left(b\right)-Ei\left(a\right)$$ The fact is i try to find a way to express the integral with the Generalized Exponential Integral and not with the Exponential Integral itself. Been a while i didn't handle special functions...